# Issue with HTML <table> widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `<table>` with 3 columns as:

```css
table {
  border: 1px dashed goldenrod;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="120">Some content</td>
    <td width="150">Some content</td>
    <td width="100%">Some content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now the 3rd column ise set to occupy the remaining width..But in my case, while it does stretch and occupy remaining width, it squeezes the first 2 columns...

If I do not give any width to the 3rd column/td, I am able to see the specified width for the first 2 columns..

Please help me.

**The table has already been set with width="100%"**

Comment: Set the width for the whole table and leave 3rd column's value empty.

Comment: Since the table has already been set with width="100%", is there some other way, where in the first 2 cols take the exact px width specified and the 3rd col takes the rest ? like width="*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the last column without width, and set table width to 100% or desired table width.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DanielDZC/6Ywkf/

Answer (score 1):

When you are specifying the width of the third `td` as `100%`, it implies that its width should be the same as its parent, which is the corresponding `tr` in this case. That's why the first and the second `td`s are being squeezed as the third `td` is trying to occupy the entire row-width.

If there is absolutely no content in the first two `td`s, then you won't be able to even see them. Since there are some content in those `td`s, browser is allocating as minimum space as possible to those two, and the rest of the width is hogged by the third div.

See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fx3J/2/) on jsfiddle about what happens when the width of the last `td` is `50%`. You will see that it occupies exactly half of the row-width.

To remedy this situation, specify a percentage width for the first two `td`s, then leave the third one's width blank. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fx3J/3/) is a demo which shows this approach.

Comment: Just to add to the above question; if I have a <table> width as 300px with 3 cols; 2cols having 100px each and 3rd col having 500px width...So in this case, will the table stretch to 700px OR will it follow the parent width of 300px ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest NOT mixing percentages and pixels. This will cause cross-browser issues etc.

You have to decide to go with % or pixels, and then just leave the 3rd column width blank.

Comment: Well I had also thought along similar lines...But the issue is I do not want to disturb the existing arrangement for the first 2 tds and only edit/fix for the 3rd column..